# Firebase and React Hooks (useState & useEffect)

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-hooks

I have a basic usage of react hooks, but it seems to fail.

Error

> Error: Invalid hook call.

Code

```
function GetUserDisplayName(userId) {
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState("Jane Doe");
  db.collection("users")
    .doc(userId)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      setDisplayName(doc.data().displayName);
    });
  return displayName;
}
```

Note, even without the db call it fails to simply return the default displayName.

Comment: put the block of code in `try` `catch` and check the errors? is that function inside the functional component? why is `useState` hook inside that function?

Comment: Do you intend to call firebase onMount or in response to a user action like a button click? techGuru's answer below addresses the former, my answer addresses the latter.

Comment: I am trying to just populate the dom with a user's name - which is stored in a users collection. This does not require user action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you posted is a method, not a custom hook. By convention, all hooks start with the word 'use'.If you want to fire an effect in your hook you must use the useEffect hook in your custom hook.

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

function useDisplayName(userId) {
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState("Jane Doe");

  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("users")
    .doc(userId)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      doc.exists && 
      doc.data().displayName && 
      setDisplayName(doc.data().displayName);
    });
  }, []);

  return displayName
}
```

The following hook will run on initialisation, like componentDidMount, if you want to change that you can add dependencies to the array in the second parameter of the effect hook. [More info on that here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html)

Comment: you are assuming `GetUserDisplayName` as a functional component ? it can be a `method` inside the `functional` component ?

Comment: hooks only work in functional components, you cannot use hooks in class components. In class components you can use regular lifecycle methods.

Comment: I know , but what i am saying is the function mentioned in the question can be a method inside the functional component ?  not the main component

Comment: A functional component is a function. Why would you wrap it in a redundant extra `GetUserDisplayName ` function method? Just call firebase in a useEffect hook in your functional component then.

Comment: You can't just fire off a firebase call in a functional component because the component does not know when to call the function. There is no trigger. That's why you need a lifecycle method, since you don't have those in functional components you use the effect hook in its place.

Comment: @JoshPittman It looks like 'unsubscribe' is declared, but never used?

Comment: I updated the example for you. Sorry, that was leftover from a previous example where I was using a real-time listener, so I unsubscribed in the unmount. You are using a get() call so no unsubscribe necessary.

Comment: @ppedrazzi please accept my answer if it helped or let me know what's not working now

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the function provided above is the `method` inside your functional `component`.

The `useState` should then be outside the method in the component.

```
const yourComponent = () => {

const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState("Jane Doe");

const GetUserDisplayName = (userId)  => {
  db.collection("users")
    .doc(userId)
    .get()
    .then(doc => {
      setDisplayName(doc.data().displayName);
    });
  return displayName;
 }

return <p> INSERT JSX HERE</p>

}
```

Comment: This answer is perfect if you don't want to use any lifecycle methods. For example if you want to get data in response to a button click or something. I am assuming the question was in the context of a lifecycle method otherwise there would be no need to use hooks at all. This is just a plain function method.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, i am not well versed with Firebase, so just googled and i totally agree with you!!!

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `useEffect` hook

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

function useDisplayName(userId) {
  const [displayName, setDisplayName] = useState("Jane Doe");
  useEffect(() => {
    db.collection("users")
      .doc(userId)
      .get()
      .then(doc => {
        setDisplayName(doc.data().displayName);
      });
  }, [userId]);

  return displayName;
}

function App() {
  const displayName = useDisplayName("Your ID");
  return <div>{displayName}</div>;
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```